# Does Fixed_alpha_shape_3() destroy or modify original triangulation?

Tags: c++, cgal

Does [Fixed_alpha_shape_3()](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Alpha_shapes_3/classCGAL_1_1Fixed__alpha__shape__3.html#affb181a32b5dfff420a8c33882e276a0) destroy or modify the underlying triangulation? The doc says "this operation destroys the triangulation" but does it replace it with the alpha shape triangulation? The source code suggests it is modifying the underlying delaunay triangulation since it is [removing vertices](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/Alpha_shapes_3/include/CGAL/Fixed_alpha_shape_3.h#L411). Further, the fact that the triangulation object is [passed as a reference](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/Alpha_shapes_3/include/CGAL/Fixed_alpha_shape_3.h#L562) also makes me think alpha shape is modifying the underlying triangulation. If it is true, it means we can continue using the original triangulation object naturally throughout the remainder of our code. If the triangulation is not modified, instead it is truly destroyed and no longer exists, can we simply use the Fixed_alpha_shape_3 object as a triangulation object since it [inherits from the Triangulation class](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/Alpha_shapes_3/include/CGAL/Fixed_alpha_shape_3.h#L110)?

The ultimate goal is to make sure cell neighbors are updated in a new triangulation object after alpha shape removes cells on the boundary. Most importantly, the new triangulation object needs to contain the correct `cell->neighbor(i)->is_inifinite` status at the boundaries.

For example, construction of the original triangulation follows as usual:

`RTriangulation T(points.begin(),points.end());`

followed by the creation of the Fixed_alpha_shape_3:

`Fixed_alpha_shape_3 as(T);`

I know we can access the alphaShape INTERIOR and EXTERIOR cells with various methods including `as.get_alpha_shape_cells()`, but if Fixed_alpha_shape_3 is simply modifying the original triangulation, `T`, then we should be able to continue using `T` as such:

```cpp
const RTriangulation::Finite_cells_iterator cellEnd = T.finite_cells_end();
for (RTriangulation::Finite_cells_iterator cell = T.finite_cells_begin(); cell != cellEnd; cell++) {
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
       if (cell->neighbor(i)->is_infinite) cell->info().p = 1;
    }
}
```

Or can I simply start using the alpha shape object instead:

```cpp
const RTriangulation::Finite_cells_iterator cellEnd = as.finite_cells_end();
for (RTriangulation::Finite_cells_iterator cell = as.finite_cells_begin(); cell != cellEnd; cell++) {
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
       if (cell->neighbor(i)->is_infinite) cell->info().p = 1;
    }
}
```

The least ideal solution would be to create new lists of cells with `as.get_alpha_shape_cells()`, because that would mean a major rehaul of our code with many logical splits. I suspect that is not necessary, which is why I am clarifying the action of `Fixed_alpha_shape_3()`.

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

The word "destroys" is an unlucky choice. As you noticed the class Fixed_alpha_shape_3 is derived from the triangulation class.   The constructor that takes the reference to  a triangulation dt as input, swaps it with dt.  So afterwards in dt you find the default constructed, that is empty triangulation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply :-) So the cell pointers extracted by `get_alpha_shape_cells()`, would have the same pointers to those in the list generated by iterating on the original RTriangulation cells?

Comment: I would say yes.